# Check if element is visible inside iframe in the same domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Here is what i am trying to achieve with jQuery.

I have website and there is iframe in one of the pages.

When i try to check if element is visible on a page i check like this:

```
if($('.tabContentContainer').is(':visible')) {
  RunFunction(1);
}
```

But when the element is inside an iframe i can not check if it is visible, why ?

Is it possible to check if element is visible inside iframe and if so how ?

Also i would like to know how to select the second loaded iframe on the page. All of the iframes do not have classes or IDs of the elements so i can't select it by them.

Comment: Could you please share the website? Or the piece of dom you want to inspect with jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `contents()` method of jquery. something like:

```
$("#your-iframe-id").contents().find('.class-you-want-to-check').is(':visible')
```